How can I create a shrinking header with a shadow effect on scroll using Bootstrap and jQuery?
I'm working on a webpage using Bootstrap 4 and jQuery, and I want to create a header that shrinks in size and adds a shadow effect when the user scrolls down the page. I've written some code that mostly works, but I'm not getting the smooth transition I want, and the shadow effect isn't consistent.
Problem:
. The header and logo should shrink when scrolling down.
. A shadow should appear under the header during the scroll.
. The transition should be smooth, but mine feels choppy.
Here's the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code I've been working with:
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <h6 id="logo" class="display-7 font-weight-bold text-dark">
                Mahyar<br>ART<br>GALERIE
            </h6>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


css:
#logo {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    transition: font-size 0.3s ease-in-out, padding 0.3s ease-in-out;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.shrink #logo {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.navbar {
    transition: padding 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.shrink .navbar {
    padding: 10px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}


JS :
#logo {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    transition: font-size 0.3s ease-in-out, padding 0.3s ease-in-out;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.shrink #logo {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.navbar {
    transition: padding 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.shrink .navbar {
    padding: 10px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}


My Issue:
The transition isn't as smooth as I'd like, especially when viewed on slower devices.
The shadow effect under the header sometimes doesn't appear correctly or flickers.
What I've Tried:
I've adjusted the transition timing but still experience choppiness.
I've tested on different browsers, but the shadow issue persists.
Question: How can I make the transition smoother and ensure the shadow effect appears consistently across different devices and browsers?

you duplicated the css part instead of sharing the javascript code

You didn't share the Javascript code you used to set/unset the shrink class when the scroll event occurs.
So it's not clear what's the actual behaviour you are experiencing as a way of comparison with any proposed solution.
By the way since you already had the css transitions defined, I just changed one selector to better match the logo and added a minimum javascript needed to add/remove the shrink class to the .navbar element.
It works correctly according to the expectation:


//on DOM ready
$(document).ready(function() {
  //adds the window scroll event handler
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    //that will add/remove the shrink class to the .navbar according to the scrollbar relative to threshold
    const threshold = 50;
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > threshold) { 
      $('.navbar').addClass('shrink');
    } else {
      $('.navbar').removeClass('shrink');
    }
  });
});
#logo {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  transition: font-size 0.3s ease-in-out, padding 0.3s ease-in-out;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.shrink #logo{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.navbar {
  transition: padding 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.navbar.shrink {
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

section {
  height: 2000px;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-rt/SrQ4UNIaGfDyEXZtNcyWvQeOq0QLygHluFQcSjaGB04IxWhal71tKuzP6K8eYXYB6vJV4pHkXcmFGGQ1/0w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <h6 id="logo" class="display-7 font-weight-bold text-dark">
        Mahyar<br>ART<br>GALERIE
      </h6>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<section>
  ...PAGE CONTENT...
</section>



